# Selenium doesn't display text

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Instead of getting text, I get something like this: **[ing]** it should be: *Premium green tea*.

```
Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".prod-ing")).Text;
```

HTML:

```
<p class="prod-ing">Premium green tea</p>
```

Both in the browser and in the html file text is displayed correctly.

Atributes like 
**textContent**
**outerText**
**innerText**
**innerHTML**

gives the same result.

[Webpage](http://www.bulkbarn.ca/en/Products/All/Organic-Matcha-Green-Tea-Powder)

Comment: Please post the html.

Comment: Add the relevant code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always test your selector in the browser dev console. Use $$() for CSS selectors and $x() for XPath. It will save you a lot of time and frustration. In this case if you do `$$(".prod-ing").length` you will see there are two elements that match this locator.

There are several locators you could substitute. A couple that I found that work are

```
"section.product_detail_copy p.prod-ing"
"section.product-description-template-target p.prod-ing"
```

I always include the tag name with the class name to be extra specific. That way if the page changes in the future, you will lower your chances of matching some other tag with the same class name.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `prod-ing` classes, the first one is with `[ing]` text. Try

```
Browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product_detail_copy .prod-ing")).Text;
```

`product_detail_copy` class is an unique ancestor of the element you are looking for.

Comment: The element is not found using this selector

Comment: @EvaldasB Edited my answer